# why crossAxisAlignment and mainAxisAlignment is different in row and column

Tags: flutter, dart, layout, flutter-layout, flutter-widget

As we all know,

For Row:

mainAxisAlignment = Horizontal Axis
crossAxisAlignment = Vertical Axis

For Column:

mainAxisAlignment = Vertical Axis
crossAxisAlignment = Horizontal Axis

But my question is why this two property perform differently in this two widget,
For row and column.

Comment: It's simple row is laid out horizontally and coloumn is laid vertically , that's all

Comment: as @basudevnayak said and it's because of the alignment options that the two provide is same for the axes of the row and column the there is no as such they perform differently. eg take the main axis for row and column which is the horizontal axis and vertical axis respectively and this is the axis that the widgets will be laid so, the alignment properties must be the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats really simple..main axis is always in the direction acoording to column or row and Cross axis is always in the opposite direction of column and row. So for column and row It is different. Fr column main axis is vertical and cross axis is horizontal and vice versa for row. Hope you understand!

Answer (score 1):

As Per my Understanding Row Widget Always Grow Horizontally  And Columns Grows Vertically ,SO it clears That MainaxisAlignment is Horizontal in Case Of Rows   And Whereas  For Colums MainaxisAlignMent is Vertical